# Como editar arquivos e compilá-los em Python + Django

Tags: python, django

Editei um arquivo .py, compilei o mesmo porém diz que não tenho permissão.

[Errorno 13] Permission denied: 'models.pyc'

Comment: Exeprimente alterar as permissões para ser mais abrangente

Comment: Efetuei um teste deletando o arquivo .pyc, a compilação ocorreu normalmente, porém, sem as alterações previstas.

Comment: Mas se o erro é esse descrito na pergunta é porque as permissões devem ser alteradas

Comment: Agora mesmo com permissão, como devo aplicar as alterações remotamente? Estou com o Python em meu pc executando a função compileall em um ambiente remoto (webserver Python + Django 1.3), porém as alterações não são aplicadas

Comment: Tente usar o "compileall"